# Copy Data from an Android Emulator that is run by Gradle Managed Devices

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, cucumber, adb, uitest

When running UITests on an Android Emulator that is managed using [Gradle managed devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices), how do I copy data like screenshots, cucumber reports etc.? I cannot use `adb pull` because the emulator is shutdown and reset instantly after each run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a little documented feature to do this:

Everything that you copy on the emulator to

```
/sdcard/Android/media/<Bundle Identifier>/additional_test_output
```

is copied to a per-managed-device subfolder in

```
app/build/outputs/managed_device_android_test_additional_output
```

after the test has been run.

Comment: This is correct, maybe it would be a good idea to mark this answer as correct! :)

Comment: Worth adding that the <Bundle Identifier> needs to match the "namespace" parameter defined within the "android" block inside benchmark module's build.gradle(.kts) file.

Comment: Not that "<Bundle Identifier>" should match the "applicationId" which might be different from "namespace"